# Powershell - Different output when reading from a file vs hard coded variable

Tags: powershell

I have a file called input.txt with the following line (the file is encoded in UTF-8-BOM)

> PDVSA PETROCEDEÑO

I have the following powershell script

```
$input = Get-Content -Path input.txt
foreach ($line in $input) {
Write-Output $line
}
Write-Output "PDVSA PETROCEDEÑO"
```

When I run this code I get the following output:

> PDVSA PETROCEDEÑO
>
> PDVSA PETROCEDEOÃ'O

So the question is, why am I getting different outputs, and how can I transform the first output into the second?

What I am trying to do is to read from the file with the same format as in the hard-coded output so I can use that string in a SOAP message

Thanks

Comment: How is the script file encoded?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The script is encoded in UTF-8

Comment: But without a BOM? Try saving the script as UTF-16LE ("Unicode" in most Windows tools)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen If I change the encoding for the script I then get the same output, but that is not what I am trying to accomplish, I have edited my main comment to clarify

Comment: So you want to deliberately use the wrong encoding for reading the file? `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($string))` should do the trick

Comment: Isn't the 2nd one the wrong one?

Comment: Did you try `Get-Content -Path input.txt -Encoding UTF8` ?